# Add method to Controller

Tags: laravel

Sorry about restating my other question but the people that commented wanted more information, like uploading snapshot or the log file I don't know how to upload here.

I wan't to add a method(not function my  mistake) to my PhotoController

```
public function search(){
    return view('photos.search');
}
```

My route

```
Route::get('/photos/search','PhotosController@search');
```

I have created the file search.blade.php in the /photos in that file is 1 word "search"

Here is the error I get when I try it in the browser.

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View:/Web/PhotoAlbum/resources/views/photos/show.blade.php)
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
@section('content')
<h3>{{$photo->title}}</h3>
```

```
/{{$photo->photo}}" alt="{{$photo->title}}">
/{{$photo->photo}}" alt="{{$photo->title}}">


{!!Form::open(['action'=> ['PhotosController@destroy', $photo->id],'method' => 'POST'])!!}
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
{{Form::submit('Delete',['class'=> "btn btn-primary"])}}
{!!Form::close()!!}
@endsection
```

Note that this error is on another page. I have not edited this page, what I stated above is all I have done also note that the program work well and this error only shows when I try to access the search page.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `$photo` variable doesn't exist in your view nor was it provided by the controller.

Try this:

```php
public function search(){
    $photo = ... // retrieve the photo 
    return view('photos.search', ["photo" => $photo]);
}
```

Comment: I am confused, there are other methods in the Controller: create and show.  They don't require the line you have added, but comunicate with the model Thank you for your help

Comment: If your the show method has this signature `show(Photo $photo)`, you might want to check [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding) out, it works the same way in a controller action but you'll need to add a route parameter to `/photos/search`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you have not compact the variable. write the function like below:

Use Your model name at the top of your controller.
use App\YourModelName;

```
public function search(){
 $photo = YourModelName::all();
 return view('photos.search', compact('photo'));
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: I have that at the top  'use App\Photo;'  see comment below also